# Point x value changes for no reason

Tags: java, matrix, methods, point

I have this method for looking for a free position inside a matrix. This is the output i get when I print the `matrix`.

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I have a `currentPos` of `(0,0)`. The next free Position should be (0,1). when I call `NextFreePos()` it will change the `currentPos.x` value even though It shouldnt change. I only change the `x` if i get a true in the second for loop, but this always returns `false`, because I make `stop = true` inside the first for loop
Here is the output I get when I run this method:

```
NEXT POS = (0;0)
SAME X
NEXT POS = (1;1) // I dont get why the x (first value) changed to 1

 public void nextFreePos(Point currentPos){
        // display the OLD POS (x,y) <-- x = row and y = column
        System.out.println("OLD POS = ("+(currentPos.x)+";"+currentPos.y+")");       
        boolean stop = false;
        // check if there is a free Pos in current row, starting from current y
        for(int y = currentPos.y; y < 7; y++){
            // check if Position is free and no free position has been found yet
            if(matrix[currentPos.x][y] == 0 && stop == false){
                stop = true;
                System.out.println("SAME X");
                currentPos.y = y;
            }
        }        
        currentPos.x++;        
        for(int x = currentPos.x; x < 7; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < 7; y++){
                // check if Position is free and no free position has been found yet
                if(matrix[x][y] == 0 && stop == false){
                    stop = true;
                    System.out.println("OTHER X");
                    // set the position to x and y
                    currentPos.x = x;
                    currentPos.y = y;  
                }                
            }
        }  
        // display the NEXT POS (x,y)
        System.out.println("NEXT POS = ("+currentPos.x+";"+currentPos.y+")");       
    }
```

Comment: You increment it with `currentPos.x++;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the highlighted piece of code.

```
NEXT POS = (0;0)
SAME X
NEXT POS = (1;1) // I dont get why the x (first value) changed to 1

 public void nextFreePos(Point currentPos){
        // display the OLD POS (x,y) <-- x = row and y = column
        System.out.println("OLD POS = ("+(currentPos.x)+";"+currentPos.y+")");       
        boolean stop = false;
        // check if there is a free Pos in current row, starting from current y
        for(int y = currentPos.y; y < 7; y++){
            // check if Position is free and no free position has been found yet
            if(matrix[currentPos.x][y] == 0 && stop == false){
                stop = true;
                System.out.println("SAME X");
                currentPos.y = y;
            }
        }
```

> ```
>         currentPos.x++;
> ```

```
        for(int x = currentPos.x; x < 7; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < 7; y++){
                // check if Position is free and no free position has been found yet
                if(matrix[x][y] == 0 && stop == false){
                    stop = true;
                    System.out.println("OTHER X");
                    // set the position to x and y
                    currentPos.x = x;
                    currentPos.y = y;  
                }                
            }
        }  
        // display the NEXT POS (x,y)
        System.out.println("NEXT POS = ("+currentPos.x+";"+currentPos.y+")");       
    }
```

Comment: Oops that was stupid... I should only do that when stop == false.

Answer (score 1):

You find an open position at (0,1) and set stop = true;, then after the first for loop you call currentPos.x++; which increments x. The next loop never does anything because stop is already false.